# PHP regular expressions: matching a bunch of terms without recording the matches

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have what I'm guessing is a fairly basic regular expression problem:

```
// Example strings

$string = "test test 24/11/2009";
$string = "test test 21-11-09";
$string = "test testtest 24.11.2009test";

$delim = "(\.|-|/)";
// dd/mm/yyyy
preg_match("#[^0-9](\d{1,2})$delim(\d{1,2})$delim(20\d{2})[^0-9]#i", $string, $result);
// dd/mm/yy
preg_match("#[^0-9](\d{1,2})$delim(\d{1,2})$delim(\d{2})[^0-9]#i", $string, $result);
```

Now I want to match the delimiters without them showing up in the $result array.

Comment: Please include example of `$string`

Comment: I included 3 examples for the 2 regular expressions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delimiter is one in ".", "-", "/": and they are not included in $result because they aren't in "()"

```
$delim = "[./-]+";
```

Comment: This regexp does not produce equal results. You need to lose the `+` quantifier: `$delim = "[\.-/]";` Otherwise: Good adaption! +1!

Comment: The `.` need not be escaped inside a character set.

Comment: Thanks, that really was a simple solution!

Comment: `-` must be escaped in a character class or put at the begining or at the end.

Comment: @M42 is right: the hyphen in `[.-/]` doesn't match a hyphen because it's being treated as a metacharacter.  Please edit your answer to incorporate the changes suggested in these comments.

Answer (score 1):

A non-capturing group should do the job:

```
$delim = "(?:\.|-|/)";
```

Comment: True, but he should have been using square brackets all along.  A character class like `[./-]` is more readable and more efficient than the equivalent alternation.

Comment: @Alan Moore: Correct! That is why i upvoted jbrond's answer :)